# Median of numbers stored in array

Tags: c, median

Problem is to calculate median of numbers. My idea is :

1. Fill array of integer with numbers using `Arraymake()` function
2. copy the address into a pointer created in `main()` function
3. pass that array to `Median()` function and calculate that median

Code:

```
    #include <stdio.h>
    #include <stdlib.h>

    int* Arraymake(size_t);//Function for creating array of numbers.
    void  Median(size_t ,int* );//Function for calculate the median.

    int main(int argc, char **argv)
    {
        size_t count;//Size of the list of numbers.
        puts("Size of the list:");
        scanf("%Iu",&count);
        int *ArResult=Arraymake(count);//Result of the first function
        Median(count,ArResult);
        free(ArResult);
        return 0;
    }

    int* Arraymake(size_t ln)   //ln~lenght
    {
        int* Array=(int*) malloc(ln*sizeof(int));
        int number ,i; //numbers filling the array

        puts("Please input numbers.\n");

        for(i=0;i<(ln);i++)
            {
                scanf("%i", &number);
                Array[i]=number;
            }
            return Array;
    }

    void  Median(size_t ln,int* Array)
    {
        float median;

        if((ln)%2==0)
            {
                    median= (Array[(ln)/2]+Array[(ln/2 )-1] )/2;
                    printf("%f",median);


            }
        else 
            {
                    median= Array[((ln-1)/2)];
                    printf("%f",median);
            }
}
```

I want to find a way to optimize my variables and make my code more self-documented? How can I improve my code?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**1.** `Arraymake`:

- Change the name to `MakeArray` as it makes more sense or name it `MakeArrayFromInput` to make it more descriptive to what it actually does
- Name the parameter `length`, as in : `int* MakeArray(size_t length)` - this 
  is descriptive and you don't have to put the comment explaining what it does
- Name local variables in `camelCase`, so `array` instead of `Array`
- Matter of preference but consider declaring `array` as `int *array` instead of `int* array` - you won't forget that the variable itself is a pointer and you have to declare additional pointers in the same statement with `*`s - `int *array, *anotherPointer;`
- `int number ,i; //numbers filling the array` - comment is redundant and you don't have to declare `i` here, you can do it in the `for` - speaking of which:
- `for(i=0;i<(ln);i++)` can become `for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)` - parentheses over `ln` are redundant, you should use better spacing to make it more readable.

---

**2.** `Median`:

- The same story with the parameter and naming, also pass the array first, then the length : `void Median(int *array, size_t length)`
- You don't have to declare the `median` variable before the `if`
- Parentheses in the `if` are redundant : `if(length % 2 == 0)`
- The calculation of the median in the case of an even number of elements is flawed - you do an integer division as both operands of `/` are `int`s - you'd have to make at least one of them a `float` e.g. like this `median= (Array[(ln)/2]+Array[(ln/2 )-1] )/2.0;` - see the `2.0` - this is a `double` literal, a floating-point number, not an `int`
- You can shorten the calculation a bit by changing `array[(length - 1) / 2];` to `array[length / 2];` in the case of an odd number - the integer division will truncate the result into what you need
- The function should do one thing - you're calculating the median and printing it in the same function. Consider making the function `Median` return the value of the median and print it somewhere else

The function then should look more or less like this :

```
float Median(int *array, size_t length)
{
    if(length % 2 == 0)
    {
        float median = (array[length / 2] + array[length / 2 - 1]) / 2.0;
        return median;
    }
    else 
    {
        float median = array[length / 2];
        return median;

        //or just simply
        return array[length / 2];
    }
}
```

Something more complex, the function can be greatly simplified by using the ternary operator `?:` :

```
float Median(int *array, size_t length)
{
    return length % 2 == 0 ? 
           (array[length / 2] + array[length / 2 - 1]) / 2.0 : 
           array[length / 2];
}
```

**However**, this is just trivia and you should aim to make your code as readable as possible

---

**3.** `main`

- I think that all of the comments are redundant here, everything is self-documenting
- Naming : `ArResult` should be something descriptive and simple - the most simple way would be to name it just `array`
- Spacing in function parameters e.g.
  `scanf("%Iu", &count);` instead of `scanf("%Iu",&count);`

---

**4.** General advice

- Work on the spacing - try to put spaces between operands and operators as in `if(length % 2 == 0)`, in places like `for` loops : `for(int i = 0; i < length; i++)` and in function parameters : `scanf("%Iu", &count);`
- Put comments before the thing they're describing, not at the end of the line - this way if you want to make it a multi-line comment you won't have problems and it's more readable that way e.g.

like this:

```
//Function for creating array of numbers.
int* MakeArray(size_t);
//Function for calculating the median.
int Median(int*, size_t);
```

This is just an example - I think the function names are descriptive enough not to put comments there, they will clutter the view :

```
int* MakeArray(size_t);
int Median(int*, size_t);
```

---

**EDIT**

What I didn't initially remember is that to calculate the median, you have to use a sorted array. You should probably do that separately

```
int *array = MakeArray(count);
qsort(array, count, sizeof(int), compare)
float result = Median(count, array);
```

The qsort is a function from `stdlib.h`. You have to also declare a function `compare` to use in it e.g.

```
int compare(const void* a, const void* b)
{
     int int_a = *((int*) a);
     int int_b = *((int*) b);

     if(int_a == int_b) return 0;
     else if (int_a < int_b) return -1;
     else return 1;
}
```

This is taken from https://stackoverflow.com/a/3893967/7931009